# Make lens aperture in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a lens aperture with different f numbers(sizes of the holes). I started with this code but it wont make it look like a complete aperture. Appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Aperture image}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) circle(1);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle(1);
\foreach \r in {0,40,...,360}
\filldraw[fill = black!80,draw = white,thick, rotate = \r] (-3,-1) rectangle (-0.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The current output is looking like this.
[image]

Comment: could you make your script compilable?

Comment: Its compiling on my machine. I made it in beamer.

Comment: If I am to copy your script as such, could you explain me how to compile it?

Comment: You need to create a beamer document and write a simple frame and paste this code in your frame. Make sure you import tikz package.

Comment: Well you can't expect someone to do that for you :) please make your script self-sufficient: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: You want me to copy the whole template?

Comment: @RD1153, Raaja means can you please begin your code with `\documentclass` and end it with `\end{document}`. This means we can just copy and paste the whole block into an editor and saves us having to guess what class and packages you are using (only include packages you need for your code, not everything). And this is probably not `beamer` specific, so it's best to use a base class like `article`.

Comment: Okay now I got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problems (+1) for MWE.

Comment: @RD1153 Also, if you consider the answers to your previous questions useful, consider accepting them :)

Comment: @Raaja I thought you were going to answer my question. I wonder why did you comment and asked me for all details if you were not going to answer my question.

Comment: @RD1153 I tried, but I could not figure out a way. However, the details is not specific for me, but for anyone who wants to answer your question. Because, when they try they should not be left to start without anything. Nevertheless, as self-containing MWE always helps :)

Comment: Okay. BTW what is MWE? Sorry for being lame ;)

Comment: @RD1153 it's never a lame question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @RD1153 Please refer the link https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks for better understanding all features in TeX.SE...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could draw triangles instead of rectangles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) circle (1);
  \foreach \r in {0,40,...,320}
    \fill[black!80,rotate=\r] (-0.5,1) -- (-0.5,-0.13) --++ (130:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks lot for the answer. Could you please tell what the (130:1) is doing there?

Comment: @RD1153, that is polar coordinates (angle:length). The angle is taken from the horizontal, so to get a triangle with a 40° angle you need 90+40=130

Comment: The ++ makes the coordinate relative to the previous one.

Comment: Okay thank you. Now I understand.

Answer (score 48):

A little late, but the following defines a `pic` that is more or less configurable (and I promptly used it to create an animation). The calculations are most likely inefficient and the overall code doesn't look as good as those posted by the usual Ti*k*Z experts.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
  {
    ,aperture segments/.initial = 6
    ,aperture radius/.initial = 3
    ,aperture closed/.initial = .5
    ,aperture/.pic={
      \begin{scope}
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/aperture segments}\segments
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/aperture radius}\rad
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/aperture closed}\closed
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ang{360/\segments}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\endang{360-\ang}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\alphtild{(180-\ang)/2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rp{(1-\closed)*\rad}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\cc{\rad*sqrt(2*(1-cos(\ang)))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bp{sqrt(\rad*\rad+\rp*\rp-2*\rad*\rp*cos(\ang))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\alphprim{asin(\rp/\bp*sin(\ang))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\alph{\alphtild-\alphprim}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bet{180-\ang-\alph}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{\cc*sin(\bet)/sin(\ang)}
        \foreach \r in {0,\ang,...,\endang}
          {
            \filldraw[fill = black!80, draw = white, thick, rotate = \r]
              (0:\rad) ++(180-\alphprim:\bb) -- (0:\rad)
              arc[start angle=0, end angle=\ang, radius=\rad]
              -- cycle;
          }%
      \end{scope}%
    }
  }

\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {0,0.025,...,1}
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic [aperture segments=9, aperture closed=\x] {aperture};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\foreach\x in {1,0.975,...,0}
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic [aperture segments=9, aperture closed=\x] {aperture};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

A small document which describes what is calculated above and why:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Aperture drawing}
\author{Skillmon}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype\mathcol[1]{>{\startmath}#1<{\endmath}}
\let\startmath\(
\let\endmath\)
\newcolumntype\macrocol[1]{>{\collectcell\makemacroname}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand\makemacroname[1]
  {%
    \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}%
  }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The geometry we use is shown in figure~\ref{fig:geom}.
In the equations below variables correspond to the names in the used
Ti\textit{k}Z code to draw the aperture. The correspondences are shown in
table~\ref{tab:corres}. In the following I don't care about the sign of the
angles denoted with $\angle P_1P_2P_3$ and always only care for their absolute
value, so $\angle P_1P_2P_3$ might actually be $\angle P_3P_2P_1$.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\segments{9}
    \def\rad{3}
    \def\closed{0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ang{360/\segments}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\endang{360-\ang}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\alphtild{(180-\ang)/2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rp{(1-\closed)*\rad}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cc{\rad*sqrt(2*(1-cos(\ang)))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bp{sqrt(\rad*\rad+\rp*\rp-2*\rad*\rp*cos(\ang))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\alphprim{asin(\rp/\bp*sin(\ang))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\alph{\alphtild-\alphprim}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bet{180-\ang-\alph}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{\cc*sin(\bet)/sin(\ang)}
    \draw 
      (0,0)       coordinate(O) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [below]{$O$}
      (0:\rad)    coordinate(A) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [below right]{$A$}
      ++(180-\alphprim:\bb)
                  coordinate(C) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [above left]{$C$}
      (\ang:\rad) coordinate(B) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [above right]{$B$}
      (\ang:\rp)  coordinate(D) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [below]{$D$}
      ;
    \draw[blue]
      (A) arc[start angle=0, end angle=40, radius=3cm] -- (C) -- cycle;
    \draw[gray, dashed]
      (O) -- (A)
      (A) -- (B)
      (O) -- (B)
      ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption
    {%
      The geometry in which we want to calculate the position of point $C$%
      \label{fig:geom}%
    }
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{\mathcol{c} \macrocol{l} \mathcol{l}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Macro name}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Meaning} \\
    \midrule
    \bar{p} & closed & \overline{DB}/\overline{OB} \\
    n & segments \\
    r & rad & \overline{OA}=\overline{OB} \\
    \gamma & ang & \angle AOB \\
    \tilde{\alpha} & alphtild & \angle OAB \\
    r_p & rp & \overline{OD} \\
    c & cc & \overline{BA} \\
    b_p & bp & \overline{AD} \\
    \alpha' & alphprim & \angle OAC \\
    \alpha & alph & \angle CAB \\
    \beta & bet & \angle ABC \\
    b & bb & \overline{AC} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption
    {%
      Variable-Macro-Correspondence and their geometrical meaning in
      figure~\ref{fig:geom}.%
      \label{tab:corres}%
    }
\end{table}

The variables we know the values of are $n$, $r$, and $\bar{p}$. $\bar{p}$ is in
the range $[0,1]$ and describes how closed the aperture is. $n$ is the number of
aperture segments and $r$ is the outer radius of the aperture. From $n$ we get
the angle $\gamma = \angle AOB$ straight forward:

\begin{equation}
  \gamma = \frac{\ang{360}}{n}
\end{equation}
Also relatively easy to calculate are the value of $p$ and $r_p$:
\begin{align}
  p &= 1 - \bar{p} \\
  r_p &= rp
\end{align}
The next thing we want to know is the angle $\angle ACB$. We know how many edges
the polygon of the aperture will have ($n$), so we know the sum
of internal angles and $\angle ACB$ is the adjacent angle of one of the internal
angles:
\begin{equation}
  \angle ACB = \ang{180} - \ang{180}  \frac{(n - 2)}{n}
    = \ang{180} \cdot (1 - 1 + \frac{2}{n}) = \frac{\ang{360}}{n} = \gamma
\end{equation}
The distances $c$ and $b_p$ can be calculated using the law of cosines:
\begin{align}
  c &= \sqrt{2r^2 - 2r^2\cos \gamma} = r \sqrt{2(1-\cos\gamma)} \\
  b_p &= \sqrt{r^2 + r_p^2 - 2rr_p\cos\gamma} \label{eq:bp}
\end{align}
We could further simplify eq.~\ref{eq:bp}, but this should suffice.
$\tilde{\alpha}$ can be calculated with the sum of internal angles in the
triangle $OAB$ since it is isosceles. With the sine theorem we can calculate
$\alpha'$ and therefore $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
\begin{align}
  \tilde{\alpha} &= \frac{\ang{180}-\gamma}{2} \\
  \alpha' &= \arcsin ( \frac{r_p}{b_p}\sin\gamma ) \\
  \alpha &= \tilde{\alpha} - \alpha' \\
  \beta &= \ang{180} - \gamma - \alpha
\end{align}
Using the sine theorem again we calculate the value of $b$ and with the position
of $A$ and the angle $\alpha'$ we get the position of $C$:
\begin{equation}
  b = c \frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma}
\end{equation}
In Ti\textit{k}Z the point $C$ is now positioned at
\verb|(0:\rad) ++(180-\alphprim:\bb)|. Now we can draw our aperture segments.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Very nice. It will be into my favorities. But the image it is very fast and too big. :-)

Comment: Am I the only one seeing a fading halo (when it opens and close) or is there someone else? @Skillmon Very nice answer!

Comment: The result is magnificent. The answer would be much more educational if you added comments explaining the role of each variable and your calculations.

Comment: @AndréC I'll try to supply a bit of explanation.

Comment: @AndréC hopefully exhaustive description added.

Comment: @Sebastiano The image isn't that big, 964k, but with 300dpi, and 3/100s per frame, which makes it look pretty smooth with the steps in use. You can just run the standalone document and after that `convert -strip -alpha deactivate -layers OptimizePlus -density 300 -delay 3 -loop 0 aperture.pdf aperture.gif` in the console.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for your explanation. However your answer it is fantastic.

Comment: What do you call *"the outer radius of the aperture"*?

Comment: @AndréC the radius of the circle around it.

Comment: Alternatively we could use `\closed` as the share of the angle `\alphtild` instead of the intersection of the two lines and the calculation would need 2 steps less (but the result would be slightly different).

Comment: Thank you for this text which is very informative. You show in (4) that the angle 
`ACB` is equal to `gamma` and in (10) that this same angle `ACB` which is then called `beta` is equal to `180°-gamma-alpha`. Why do you recalculate this angle in (10) if you calculated it in (4)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is a typographical error: `beta` is the angle `ABC` and not the angle `ACB`.

Comment: @AndréC you're right, `\beta` should be `\angle ABC`, I'll correct this.